Can not control slide show images with dot pagination
I need to control slider images with the bottom dot pagination properly. But something I'm missing or doing wrong in the code.
You can check the working demo here- https://playcode.io/2070692
The entire code is-
The HTML:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>Slideshow with JS</title>
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="app.css"
        />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
                <img
                    src="img/img_nature_wide.jpg"
                    style="width: 100%"
                />
                <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
                <img
                    src="img/img_snow_wide.jpg"
                    style="width: 100%"
                />
                <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
                <img
                    src="img/img_mountains_wide.jpg"
                    style="width: 100%"
                />
                <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">4/4</div>
                <img
                    src="img/img_lights_wide.jpg"
                    style="width: 100%"
                />
                <div class="text">Caption Four</div>
            </div>

            <a class="prev">❮</a>
            <a class="next">❯</a>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div style="text-align: center">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </div>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


The CSS:
    * {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}

The JS:
const showSlides = (n) => {
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(' active', '');
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += ' active';
};

showSlides(slideIndex);

document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('clicked');
    showSlides((slideIndex += -1));
});

document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('clicked');
    showSlides((slideIndex += 1));
});

const currentSlide = (n) => {
    showSlides((slideIndex = n));
};

const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');

dots.forEach((dot) => {
    dot.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(`${slideIndex}`);
        currentSlide(slideIndex + 1);
    });
});

Now I want to control the slideshow using the dot pagination, you can check the demo also, but it's not working as expected. I suspect the issue in the JS code is in this part.
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');

dots.forEach((dot) => {
    dot.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(`${slideIndex}`);
        currentSlide(slideIndex + 1);
    });
});


Please add more detail to the question itself. What do you mean by "But something I'm missing or doing wrong in the code"? What is it currently doing and what should it be doing?

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

"The entire code" is still missing the relevant html.

I've added HTML, CSS and JS for the snippet. Kindly check.

Thank you for adding the code to the question, but you still need to explain what's wrong, and what you expect

I want to control the slider with the below dot buttons but stuck.

Are there any errors in your dev console?

No, but if I keep clicking on the dots, it's not linking the correct number of image with the dot that has been clicked, You can check the sample here - https://playcode.io/2070692

By the way, in the code posted here, you neglected to initialize slideIndex, so it doesn't work.

In your dot event listeners, you are passing slideIndex to currentSlide(). However, by the time the dots are clicked on, slideIndex has been incremented several times. I think it would be better to add a data-index attribute to each dot, and use that as the argument.

html: <span class="dot" data-index="1"></span><span class="dot" data-index="2"></span><span class="dot" data-index="3"></span><span class="dot" data-index="4"></span>; js: dot.addEventListener('click', (e) => {         const index = e.target.getAttribute("data-index");         currentSlide(index)     });

Assuming you problem is that when you click on the dots, the images go on like when you click on the errors:
The problem is that at handling the click on the dot you set the next slide to the currentSlide + 1, and therefore are exactly doing what the next button does
Instead, you have to set it to the index of the dot:
dots.forEach((dot, index) => {
  dot.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(`${index}`);
    currentSlide(index + 1);
  });
});

Note that it might be cleaner to set the index as an property on the individual dot html elements and then use these as indexes
